# How to get Cox & Snell, Nagelkerke R-Square in R logistic regression output?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, logit, r-squared

I'm new to R (used to work with SPSS), and looking for a function that will output the Cox & Snell and Nagelkerke R-Square measures of logistic regression. In SPSS they are displayed as part of the regular output, but in R I'm not sure what manipulation should I employ on the `glm` summary to output those measures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the R `rms` package the `lrm` function outputs a large number of indexes including Nagelkerke (but not Cox-Snell).  If you have $\LaTeX$ installed you can get the output automatically nicely typeset.

```
require(rms)
f <- lrm(y ~ rcs(age,4) * sex + race)
f     # same as print(f)
print(f, latex=TRUE)   # LaTeX markup, especially for use with knitr
```

The various statistics are defined in the binary logistic regression chapter in my online Regression Modeling Strategies [course notes](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rms) where you can also see `lrm` output printed.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found the following very helpful package which provides exactly the measures I was interested in:

http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/bayloredpsych/docs/PseudoR2